# Страница не растягивается не знаю как правильно применить min-height

Tags: html, css

Есть шаблон

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: GOST;
  src: url(fonts/GOST.ttf);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "GOST";
  font-size: 16px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #330066;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover:after,
a:focus:after {
  width: 100%;
}
div.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
div.kolonna {
  float: left;
  width: 91px;
}
div.up {
  background-image: url(../images/up.png);
  width: 91px;
  height: 88px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div.center {
  background-image: url(../images/center.png);
  width: 91px;
  background-repeat: x-repeat;
  height: calc(100% - 141px);
}
div.down_l {
  background-image: url(../images/down_l.png);
  width: 91px;
  height: 53px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div.down_r {
  background-image: url(../images/down_r.png);
  width: 91px;
  height: 53px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div.pageContent {
  width: calc(100% - 182px);
  height: calc(100% - 112px);
  float: left;
}
div.plintus {
  background-image: url(../images/plintus.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
}
div.contentMenuSite {
  height: 88px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.contentDWG {
  height: 300px;
}
div.Content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
div.menuStart {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
div.textLeftPos {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#menuNum1Index {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#menuNum2Index {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#menuNum3Index {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#menuNum1InfoHidden {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#menuNum2InfoHidden {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#menuNum3InfoHidden {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
#decor_img {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
div.mainMenu {
  padding-top: 27px;
}
div.textPage {
  text-align: left;
}
.round {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #330066;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="kolonna">
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="down_l"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageContent">

    <div class="contentMenuSite">
      <div class="mainMenu">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

    <div class="plintus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="kolonna">
    <div class="up"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="down_r"></div>
  </div>
```

Ни как не могу понять что правильно применить что бы растягивался центральный элемент ( content который ) что бы за ним тянулись и (kolonna center)

Comment: Ваш пример кода не работает [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)